# Unity RegisterType - Avoid UI references to middle-tier dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have a solution with to projects, Api (WebApi project) and Domain (library project).  I am using Unity as my IoC.  Domain has a dependency on Lib (a 3rd party library).  I want to RegisterType(); in my Unity registration, which is located in the Api project.

What is the recommended way to do this?

1. Reference 3rd party in both the Domain and Api just to allow RegisterType?
2. Create a UnityConfig class in the Domain that takes the Unity container as an input?
3. Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Reference both 3rd party and Domain in your Web API project and make your container setup in the Web API.

The best place to setup the container is the so called [`composition root`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of your application. So for example if you are using a self host, that would be the hosting project that will reference all the others and perform the container setup. If your Web API host is just an ASP.NET application then that would be the `Application_Start` method where you should wire the dependencies meaning that this project must reference all the others.

So you could have the following projects (each referencing all the previous):

1. Library(ies) with some domain logic
2. Web API controllers and stuff which will expose the REST facade of the referenced library(ies)
3. Host application (that's the composition root)